# dynamically added title howto

Tags: codeigniter, templates

I am using the excellent phil sturgeon template library, however I was wondering how do I assign dynamically any headings or titles to any part of my partials? Like I have a sidebar that has a login form. if Login is successful, I would like the heading that says for example 'Login' to say 'Welcome' if login is successful without creating a partial of just the h2 tags. But as a side note I noticed that the userguide of the template library doesn't mention the append_css and append_js functions at all? I saw this in someone's sample code and was wondering why that is?

Thanks anyway for all the support!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I actually was working on something that prompted this question. I will edit my post and add what I was doing as much as I can so as to make my point clear..thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

you can use functions *prepend_metadata()* or *append_metadata* in the controller  and then *echo $template['metadata']* in the view